# Delete all occurrences of string in selected text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete all occurrences of double brackets containing words in a selected block of text only and not an entire document.  Within the same selected block of text, I want to find one of three specific strings, delete the string, and insert a tab where the string was formerly located.

I worked with the Record Macro function to get the code for finding the double bracket occurrences and the specific strings, but as soon as I go to delete the found occurrence, the selection changes such that I can no longer search my original selected block of text only.

My problem is how to string together essentially 4 searches - 3 being exact strings that get deleted/replaced by a tab and 1 being a wildcard search - with all 4 of the searches limited to a block of text that is selected when I begin execution of the macro.

Comment: A quick google search turned [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692875.aspx) up.

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far. Your problem description isn't exact enough for us to repro what you have and what you want to do. Please also provide some examples of what you need to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub formattedtext()
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Range
Set rng = Selection.Range
With rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Text = "()"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End With
Set rng = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

If you mean double bracket containing words like `in the ((end)) it doesn't even matter.` you can replace

```
.MatchWildcards = False
.Text = "()"
```

with

```
.MatchWildcards = True
.Text = "\(\([A-Za-z 0-9α-ω,^13*.;:'"]{1,}\)\)"
```

this will match any words between (()). You can replace the content in [] in .Text string to match your need.